# How to get Id through @Input and @Output in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, input

I am building up an application in angular, in which i need to send and receive the data as dynamic.

**Child Component Html**:

```
<div class="selectDropdown">
    <div class="user-chip newChip" *ngFor="let user of userSelects">
        {{user}}
    </div>
    <input name="suggestion" type="text" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Type User here..." (click)="suggest()" [(ngModel)]="userSelectsString"
 id="autocomplete-input">
    <label class="fa fa-caret-down dropdownIcon"></label>

    <ul id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-items" *ngIf="show">
        <li *ngFor="let selected of suggestions" [ngClass]="isSelected(selected) ? 'selected-suggestion' : ''" (click)="selectSuggestion(selected)">
            {{ selected }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Child TS**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './child.component.scss' ]
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    userSelectsString = '';
      @Input() suggestions;
  @Output() onSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  userSelects = [];
  activeSuggestions = this.suggestions;

  show: boolean = false;

  suggest() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  isSelected(s: any) {
    return this.userSelects.findIndex((item) => item.id === s.id) > -1 ? true : false;
  }

  selectSuggestion(s): void {
    this.userSelects.find((item) => item.id === s.id) ?
      this.userSelects = this.userSelects.filter((item) => item.id !== s.id) :
      this.userSelects.push(s);
    this.show = false;
    this.userSelectsString = "";
    this.onSelected.emit(s);
  }
}
```

**App component Html**:

```
<child [suggestions]="userlist" (onSelected)="OnClickUsername($event)"></child>
```

**App component Ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  userList: any = [{ "id": "001", "name": "mango" }, { "id": "002", "name": "apple" }, { "id": "003", "name": "banana" }, { "id": "004", "name": "pine" }, { "id": "005", "name": "orange" }, { "id": "006", "name": "chery" }, { "id": "007", "name": "watermelon" }, { "id": "008", "name": "grapes" }, { "id": "009", "name": "lemon" }];

  userlist: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
        for(let i=0; i<this.userList.length; i++) {
        this.userlist.push(this.userList[i].name);
      }
      console.log(this.userlist);
 }

   OnClickUsername(username) {
    console.log(username)
  }

}
```

Here what i am doing is when user clicks on the input box, a list of items will be displayed, in which the user selected value will be emitted through `@Output() onSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();`.
The data is passed through `@Input`.

You could able to see the scenario in **Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ny7dbm

Here the functionality wise everything works fine.. The final selected username is displayed by,

```
   OnClickUsername(username) {
    console.log(username)
  }
```

I am sending the input data by using,

```
for(let i=0; i<this.userList.length; i++) {
this.userlist.push(this.userList[i].name);
```

}

Where `userlist` is the data i am sending as @Input. In the above as i am passing `this.userList[i].name` i am getting the final result as name.

But i need to get the id also in the final result..
Because i need to fetch the id of the selected user list to proceed further.
But id should not be displayed anywhere.
The sending of data should be dynamic because i can use this scenario anywhere so i cannot fetch by giving `{{selected.name}}` (Why because, here it is name, if i use it in any other component then there will be different value in the place of `name`) in the below,
I can only change the parent `app component` for data changes.

```
<li *ngFor="let selected of suggestions" [ngClass]="isSelected(selected) ? 'selected-suggestion' : ''" (click)="selectSuggestion(selected)">
            {{ selected }}
        </li>
```

(ie) If i choose `cherry` then i need to get the id `006` in final result.

Kindly help me to achieve the result of fetching the id along with the username in the user selection..

Comment: Please create a StackBlitz if possible

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera, ALready created and listed in the question.. I think you didn't see it.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ny7dbm

Comment: Sorry. My bad.!

Answer (score 1):

Send the complete **userList** in **@Input**

in `app.component.html`

```
<child [suggestions]="userList" (onSelected)="OnClickUsername($event)"></child>
```

in your `child.component.ts`

```
selectSuggestion(s): void {

    this.onSelected.emit(s);
  }
```

and finally in `app.component.ts`

```
OnClickUsername(username) {
    console.log('name => ',username.name)
    console.log('id =>', username.id)
  }
```

and when you selected the perticular thing then pass complete object

update [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fulqi3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) demo

Comment: I am not able to display the selected value inside the selected box in your solution.. If i select any value that value needs to be displayed in the input box..

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the complete solution before, I already mentioned in question that i cannot change anything in the ```child component``` You had given ```{{ selected.name }}``` Here i am getting inputs with name in another component if i use it there will be different thing in place of ```name``` so i can give only ```selected```. I can change anything in parent component but cant change in child component because i need to use this dropdown wherever i want without duplication.

Comment: I understand your problem, but if you not send complete object from parent component then not possible emit selected id...if you can see the every external packages which we are use in project that all have some specific data format... for e.g if u install some ng-select then it also need to be specific data

Comment: and if you wanted to this autocomplete as globally then you have to convert your data as autocomplete needed.

Comment: OK ! let's see, other people answers..what they will suggest to you

Comment: Externalize the key name then eg in child.ts: @Input() suggestionKey:string; in child.html {{selected[suggestionKey]}}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you cannot change the child component. You can try to filter parent userList by name. The problem of this solution - duplicated names in the list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  userList: any = [{ "id": "001", "name": "mango" }, { "id": "002", "name": "apple" }, { "id": "003", "name": "banana" }, { "id": "004", "name": "pine" }, { "id": "005", "name": "orange" }, { "id": "006", "name": "chery" }, { "id": "007", "name": "watermelon" }, { "id": "008", "name": "grapes" }, { "id": "009", "name": "lemon" }];

  userlist: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
        for(let i=0; i<this.userList.length; i++) {
        this.userlist.push(this.userList[i].name);
      }
      console.log(this.userlist);
 }

   OnClickUsername(username) {
    console.log(this.userList.find(x => x.name === username));
  }

}
```

Comment: What would be the solution if the data contains ```{"id":"001","name":"apple"},{"id":"002","name":"apple"}``` Same name but different ```id```???

Comment: Exactly never compares with name.

Comment: Find returns only first found value. As I sad above the duplicate names are problem